# How to get What elements are added or removed from collection in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have implemented PostCollectionUpdateEventListener in hibernate i am wondering is there any way to find out the changed data in the collection

Answer (score 0):

```
PersistentCollection collection = event.getCollection();

collection.getValue();
```

this gave me my desired result